# Авторизация доменных пользователей

Tags: c, windows, active-directory

Есть система клиент-сервер. Мне нужно перевести ее на доменную аутентификацию и авторизацию.

По аутентификации мануалы я нашел. SSPI функции, `InitializeSecurityContext`/`AcceptSecurityContext` и всякое шифрование.

А вот как сделать авторизацию? Т.е. на контроллере домена для пользователя `User` должна задаваться некоторая **кастомная** политика безопасности (отдельный вопрос как такую политику создавать, чтобы в дальнейшем администратор домена мог применить ее к конкретным пользователям?) и при подключении к моему серверу нужно как-то проверить имеет ли пользователь конкретные права или нет.

И похожий вопрос. Пользователь на рабочей станции домена запускает мою программу. Мне нужно проверить в своей программе есть ли у пользователя, который ее запустил, определенные права?

Comment: Как вариант... Подключаетесь с программы к LDAP анонимно (с правами учётки текущего пользователя). Потом смотрите с под-кого подключилось, и можно так же посмотреть роли, в которых пользователь состоит. Возможно это можно и без LDAP делать.

Comment: Меня не интересует логин текущего пользователя. Мне нужно узнать есть ли у него права. И как эти права добавить?